# Deploy standalone war file in liferay tomcat

Tags: liferay, tomcat7, liferay-6

I am trying to deploy a simple standalone war file in liferay tomcat version. It is neither a portlet nor theme. How can I configure the war file to be deployed as a standalone war in liferay tomcat.

I am getting following error

> 16:45:51,175 ERROR [localhost-startStop-1][HotDeployImpl:211]
>   com.liferay.portal.kernel.deploy.hot.HotDeployException: Error
>   registering portlets for travelinsurancetravelinsurance

So, I simply want to skip this registration as a portlet and access in by the url. Is this possible?

Comment: Which version of Liferay? On Liferay 6.2 I deployed (copy into deploy folder) the geoserver works without any issue (and it's not a portlet either)

Answer (score 1):

What did you try so far? Just deployed to tomcat `webapps` directory? That should work. Make sure your plugin does not have any Liferay-recognized deployment descriptor, then everything should work and any complaints by Liferay can be ignored. Don't go through Liferay's `deploy` directory if you're not deploying a Liferay component.